# Return List Items from .DLL and show them in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, list, dll

I need to make a `DLL` class library which takes `JSON` formatted properties from the `HTTP` site and displays them in a `List`. When I made a `Test` application (executable, not `DLL`) it works and does what I want but I'm having problems when making .`DLL` and trying to call it from executable application (the items should be displayed in a WPF ListBox). In my `DLL` I have following classes:

```
public class Definitions
{
    public double id { get; set; }
    public double uid { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public double dur { get; set; }
    public string project { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        dur = dur / 100000;
        return string.Format(
            "TimeID: {0}, UserID: {1}, Name: {2}, Project: {3}, Start: {4}, End: {5}, Duration: {6} min", 
            this.id,
            this.uid,
            this.user,
            this.project,
            Convert.ToDateTime(this.start),
            Convert.ToDateTime(this.end),
            this.dur);
    }
}

public class MainList
{
    public List<Definitions> data { get; set; }      
}
```

And I suppose I'm not writing the method right:

```
public static ??returntype?? GetData()
{ 
    //...
    var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    var allDefinitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainList>(f);

    if (allDefinitions.data.Count == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    return allDefinitions.data;//??
}
```

I don't know what should be the return type. When I made the `Test` application I put my code into a loop and it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allDefinitions.data.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(allDefinitions.data[i]);
}
```

But in that case it was an `EXE` application and the code was in the `Main` method. Now it should be `DLL` and should display all these `ListItems` in a `WPF ListBox`. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: 
I think I'm having problem with the method itself and with the object instances in the `Main` method. The method has to iterate through the WEB pages,'cause API only allows 50 items per request and if there's more then 50 then I have to go to the 2nd page and so on. I get 2 problems, the first one is I get an error that `not all paths return a value` and it's `page++` that is unreachable and the second one is if I say in my `Main` method `List<Definitions> myList = GetData();` then I get `Cannot implicitly convert type void into System.Collections.GenericList<Definitions>` I'm posting the whole method:

```
public static List<Definitions> GetData()
    { 
        string result = "";


        for (int page = 1; result != null; page++)
        {
            string fpage = "&page=" + page;                            
            string ApiToken = "something";
            string url = " https://someWebSite" + fpage;                          
            string userpass = ApiToken + ":api_token";
            string userpassB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userpass.Trim()));
            string authHeader = "Basic " + userpassB64;

            HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            authRequest.Method = "GET";
            authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();

                var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

               var allDefinitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainList>(f);

                if (allDefinitions.data.Count == 0)
                {

                    break;
                }


                return allDefinitions.data;

            }
```

Comment: Did you put `__declspec`s and similar?

Comment: Looks like `GetData` should return a `List<Definitions>` (what `allDefinitions.data` is)

Comment: @crashmstr yes I tried that and then `return allDefinitions.data;` but then I get error `not all code paths return a value`.

Comment: @user3613744 - That error has nothing to do with the return type.  It's telling you that there are potential paths in the code that will not return anything.

Comment: @user3613744 then you are not showing all of the code. You just need to make sure you return something (`null` or `new List<Definitions>()`) if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can return 'allDefinitions.data;' like you expected, then on the WPF Application do the same loop you did over the data you received and add them to a an ObservableCollection which is binded to the 'itemsource' of the listview.

i.e. on the WPF App after you received the data from the DLL

```
 for (var i = 0; i < allDefinitions.data.Count; i++)
            {

                myListItems.Add(allDefinitions.data[i]);

            }
```

Note that myListItems is an ObservableCollection that implements a raise to INotifyPropertyChanged on its setter.

Answer (score 0):

Return `alldefinitions.data` and return type should be `List<Definitions>` from the function GetData().

```
public static List<Definitions> GetData()
{ 
    var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    var allDefinitions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainList>(f);

    return allDefinitions.data;
}
```

Then in your WPF application, you would just iterate your list and add items to the Listbox

```
 List<Definitions> myList = GetData();
 for (var i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
 {
      ListBoxItem newItem = new ListBoxItem();
      newItem.Content = myList[i];
      YourListBox.Items.Add(newItem);
 }
```

**EDIT**
 Looks like from your comment you are trying to get 50 definitions for 5 pages.

```
public static List<Definitions> GetData()
{ 
    string result = "";
    List<Definitions> allDefinitions =  new List<Definitions>();
    for (int page = 1; page <= 5; page++)
    {
      for( int i = 0;i < 50;i++)
      {
        string fpage = "&page=" + page;                            
        string ApiToken = "something";
        string url = " https://someWebSite" + fpage;                          
        string userpass = ApiToken + ":api_token";
        string userpassB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userpass.Trim()));
        string authHeader = "Basic " + userpassB64;

        HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        authRequest.Method = "GET";
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        var definition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Definitions>(f);
        allDefinitions.Add(definition);
      }
    }
    return allDefinitions;
 }
```

Comment: yes I tried that but the problem is I can't call the method from my application (don't know why)

Comment: Are you referencing the dll in your application?

Comment: yes I am. I can get GetData(); as a static function, but I can't connect it to the list.  In the end I get NullException

Comment: If I say in my Main method List<Definitions> myList = GetData(); then I get Cannot implicitly convert type void into System.Collections.GenericList<Definitions>. I posted the whole method maybe I'm making mistake somewhere else

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect result != null is not a valid condition,use page value say page<50.return should be outside the loop.Your requirement is confusing.

Comment: yes return should be outside the loop but it doesn't work still. My requirement is: I can get 50 items per request ( per page) then for the next 50 I should do it all over again ( every time with authorisation and new request). That's why it's in the loop so it can get all the pages. If there's like 5 pages it should return a list with 250 items (5*50). Then from the EXE application it should display all these items in a ListBox. Also there I have problems with object instances 'cause I'm not able to connect the method (or I don't know how) with an object so I get a list with all items.

Comment: From the description of the comment looks like you need to 50 definitions for 5 pages,which means List<5* 50 Definitions> is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111542/discussion-between-inquisitive-mind-and-user3613744).